# @Input as Observable<string> in Angular 2/4/5

Tags: angular

This sample intention was to check ChangeDetection.

When i am trying to pass data from homecomponent to childcomponent using @input property which is an Observable gives the below Error :

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
at changeDetectionChildComponent.ngOnInit (child.component.ts:20)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (provider.ts:275)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (view.ts:456)
at checkAndUpdateNode (view.ts:417)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (services.ts:235)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (services.ts:294)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (parent.html:4)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (services.ts:273)
at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:345)
at callViewAction (view.ts:700) TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

Below is the sample Project i have created

**home.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

    @Component({
        selector:'changeDetectorHome',
        templateUrl:'ChangeDetection/Views/parent.html'
      })
      export class changeDetectionHomeComponent {
      myData:{firstname:string,lastname:string}
      message:string;
        constructor(){

            this.myData={
                firstname: 'Debasish',
                lastname:'K'
            }
        }


        changeName() {
          this.myData.firstname = 'Brad';
          this.myData.lastname='pitt';
          this.message="somedata";
              }
      }
```

**home.html** -view of home component

```html
 <h1>{{myData.firstname}} {{myData.lastname}}</h1>
  
 <button (click)="changeName()">Change name</button>
         
<child [passObjectTochild]="myData" [passStringTochild]="message"></child>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
        import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
        import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";


        @Component({
            selector:'child',
            templateUrl:'ChangeDetection/Views/child.html',
            changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
          })
         export  class changeDetectionChildComponent implements OnInit{

           @Input('passObjectTochild') data:{firstname:string,lastname:string};
           @Input('passStringTochild') data1:Observable<string>;
           counter:number=0;
            constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){

            }

            ngOnInit(){
              this.data1.subscribe(
              ()=>{
                this.counter ++;

            })}


          }
```

**changeDetection.Module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import {BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
    import { changeDetectionHomeComponent } from "./home.component";
    import { changeDetectionChildComponent } from "./child.component";

    @NgModule({
        imports:[BrowserModule],
        declarations:[changeDetectionHomeComponent,changeDetectionChildComponent],
        bootstrap:[changeDetectionHomeComponent]
    })
    export class changeDetectionModule{ }
```

**main.ts**

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
import { changeDetectionModule } from './changedetection.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(changeDetectionModule);
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure that `message` is defined, when  it is passed into component?

Comment: what is data1 ?

Comment: 2) And why you define data1 like `@Input('passStringTochild') data1:Observable<string>;`, but pass string value `message: string`?

Comment: You're NOT passing an Observable :( data1 is a string!!. If you want to count how many times change the string "data1", use @ Input() get /set   -in set you increment count-

Comment: yes message is defined in parent. @Mixalloff

Comment: data 1 is the input parameter for child @haifzhan

Comment: I was trying to look into the change detection concept so tried to put put input as an Observable .But generally cant we use input as Observable.Mixalloff can you let me know how to pass data as Observable  @Mixalloff

Comment: You need to define `message` like `message: Subject<string> = new Subject()` and emit new value like `message.next(newValue)`

Comment: You need to define `message` like `message: Subject<string> = new Subject()` and emit new value like `message.next(newValue)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize your observable in your child component and put a default value , that is causing the error, try this solution

```
 @Input('passStringTochild') data1:Observable<string>= Observable.of(null);
```

in that way your observable always  is going to be initialized, when you pass the input from the parent will be overwritten

Comment: ''of "  does not exists on Observable

Comment: you can use the normal operator "of" if you imported from import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';